# Session in mvc + URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just started having this issue with my application.

I launch my application with F5 and do what ever i am suppose to and close the application.
The last visited url say  localhost:xxxxx/Views/Book/Book.cshtml

I launch my application again. The application should start from the start page localhost:xxxxx  but it does not happen. For some reason the last url visited is retained and on relaunching the last url is opend again.  So on relaunching my application starts from localhost:xxxxx/Views/Book/Book.cshtml again.

What should i do to default the start url to be localhost:xxxxx instead of localhost:xxxxx/Views/Book/Book.cshtml or what ever was my last url and not have to go to debug and "Start New Instance" every time.

Comment: Are you using Session?  My intial thought is maybe when you debugged, you stopped in the last View you debugged.  By starting up debug again, you would automatically land on that same View.  Some code would help too.

Comment: Well yes i am using session but for exchanging data between view but that has nothing to do with URL. What type of code ??